# How to do the calculation among rows in R

Tags: r, duplicates

> I have a dataset with duplicated Ids, how can I calculate
>
> 1. A+B (get the summation of the value of A and B) for each ID
> 2. A/B (calculate A/B)for each ID
> 3. Include the results into the data set.

```
ID<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5)
Test<-c("A","B","A","A","B","C","A","C","B")
Time<-c(3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,4)
value<-c(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
data<-data.frame(ID,Test,Time,value)




  ID   Test  Time     value
        1     A     3      5
        1     B     3      6
        2     A     4      7
        3     A     4      8
        3     B     4      9
        3     C     4     10
        4     A     3     11
        4     C     3     12
        5     B    4      13
```

Comment: First off, what have you tried that didn't work? Second, what to do with ID's that doesn't have both A and B?

Comment: Untested:  `with(yourData, tapply(value, ID, function(x) x[Test=='A'] / x[Test=='B']))`. Replace `/` with `+` for 1. See `?merge` for 3.

Comment: Do does the output have the same number of rows? Can we assume there is always an A and B (no more, no less)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, drop the column `Time` since you do not need it, then `spread` out the column `value` to multiple columns and let the column `Test` tell you into which column to spread them:

*[EDIT/Remark: The data set in this answer is referring to OP's original data set, which was later edited by OP]*

```
library(tidyr) # for spread(.)
tab <- read.table(text=
"ID   Test  Time     value
1     A     jan      5
1     B     feb      6
2     A     march    7
3     A     jan      8
3     B     feb      9
3     C     march   10
4     A     jan     11
4     C     feb     12
5     B     june    13", header=TRUE)

tmp <- subset(tab, TRUE, select=c(-Time)) # Remove column Time, keep all rows (TRUE)
tmp <- spread(tmp, Test, value)
tmp
##   ID  A  B  C
## 1  1  5  6 NA
## 2  2  7 NA NA
## 3  3  8  9 10
## 4  4 11 NA 12
## 5  5 NA 13 NA

tmp$r1 <- with(tmp, A/B)
tmp$r2 <- with(tmp, A+B)
tmp
##   ID  A  B  C        r1 r2
## 1  1  5  6 NA 0.8333333 11
## 2  2  7 NA NA        NA NA
## 3  3  8  9 10 0.8888889 17
## 4  4 11 NA 12        NA NA
## 5  5 NA 13 NA        NA NA
```

This will return NA if A or B data to calculate for a certain id are missing.

It's good that you have your original data nicely stored in a tall/tidy format, it makes it easy to transform it to compare/aggregate/... whatever aspects you are interested in.

---

**Remark** if you are annoyed by the temporary variable, you can use [the pipe](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)

```
library(magrittr)
result <-(   tab 
         %>% subset( TRUE, select=c(-Time)) # Remove column Time
         %>% spread(Test, value)
         %>% within({ r1 <- A/B
                      r2 <- A+B
                   })
         )

result

##   ID  A  B  C        r1 r2
## 1  1  5  6 NA 0.8333333 11
## 2  2  7 NA NA        NA NA
## 3  3  8  9 10 0.8888889 17
## 4  4 11 NA 12        NA NA
## 5  5 NA 13 NA        NA NA
```

Comment: great job, thanks, I will accept it. But I need to keep time as a variable in my data set. I tried to make it simpler and suppose that each id has the same time for all its elements. Is there any way to keep the time in the final data set? (Please look at the new data set  above)

Comment: That's exactly the point, you have to decide how to deal with different time values while `spread`ing. As your new data set has the same time for same ID, you can just omit the `subset` line in my answer and it will work. If time values are different for the same ID, `spread` will produce multiple lines for that ID, filling up missing `A`,`B` and `C` values with `NA`. If you have multiple times per ID, you might think about splitting off `ID` and `time` in a distinct data set, dealing with that problem as appropriate for your case and then later use `merge` (or `full_join` when using dplyr)...

Comment: ... to again add the time information by using `ID` as the identifying column ("key" in database terms / `by=` argument for merge)

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @akraf's answer, but with `dplyr` syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  select(-Time) %>%
  spread(Test, value) %>%
  mutate(sum = A+B,
         ratio = A/B)
```

**Result:**

```
  ID  A  B  C sum     ratio
1  1  5  6 NA  11 0.8333333
2  2  7 NA NA  NA        NA
3  3  8  9 10  17 0.8888889
4  4 11 NA 12  NA        NA
5  5 NA 13 NA  NA        NA
```